# Receive Camunda activity name in external task handler

Tags: spring-boot, events, remote-server, camunda, business-process-management

Using an external task handler I am subscribing to Camunda events. The events are captured and the external task details are populated in the callback method (camunda-external-task-client-spring).

Is the Activity name supposed to be included as well? Do I need a follow up call to get that? I’m currently seeing only the ActivityId and ActivityInstanceId but these are of no use. In my BPM diagram it’s stated as

```xml
<bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent id=“Event_id” name=“Register”>
```

but I am not receiving the ‘Register’ part at all.